# what is the best way to draw and smoothly anti-alias draw objects and move them

Tags: delphi

I need to make a form on which I can add objects. I need to draw those objects (simple rectangles), fill them with gradient, the object contains text and there need to be lines between certains objects.

I created a descendant of TPaintbox :

```
  TKTPaintbox = class(TPaintbox)
    procedure Paint; override;

    procedure ControlMouseDown(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton; Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
    procedure ControlMouseMove(Sender: TObject; Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
    procedure ControlMouseUp(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton; Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);

  private
    FText:     string;
    FDownX:    integer;
    FDownY:    Integer;
    FDragging: Boolean;
    FBrush:    TBrush;
    FMiddle:   TPoint;

    procedure SetText(const Value: string); virtual;
  public
    constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent); override;
    destructor Destroy; override;
  published
    property Text:              string  read FText  write SetText;
    property Brush:             TBrush  read FBrush write FBrush;
    property Dragging:          boolean read FDragging;
  end;

procedure TKTFilePaintBox.Paint;
var
  w:  integer;
  h:  integer;
begin
  inherited;

  w := Round(Canvas.TextWidth(ShortFileName) / 2);
  h := Round(Canvas.TextHeight(ShortFileName) / 2);

  Canvas.Pen.Width := 1;
  Canvas.Pen.Color := clNavy;
  Canvas.Brush     := FBrush;

  Canvas.Ellipse(1,1,width,height);
  Canvas.TextOut(round(Width/2)-w, Round(Height/2)-h, ShortFileName);
end;
```

Well, that works, but the graphics are awful. So I searched for anti-aliasing and tried the Graphics32 library.

```
var
  i:  integer;
  LinearGradFiller:  TLinearGradientPolygonFiller;
begin
  ImgView32.Bitmap.Clear(clWhite32);

  FGradient.ClearColorStops;
  FGradient.AddColorStop(Stop1, FColorFrom);
  FGradient.AddColorStop(Stop2, FColorTo);

  FGradientLUT := TColor32LookupTable.Create;
  FGradient.FillColorLookUpTable(FGradientLUT);

  if FFileCount > -1 then
  begin
    for i := 0 to Length(FFile)-1 do
    begin
      LinearGradFiller            := TLinearGradientPolygonFiller.Create(FGradientLUT);
      LinearGradFiller.WrapMode   := TWrapMode(1);

      LinearGradFiller.StartPoint := FFile[i].GradientFrom;
      LinearGradFiller.EndPoint   := FFile[i].GradientTo;

      PolygonFS(ImgView32.Bitmap, FFile[i].Points, LinearGradFiller);
      PolyLineFS(ImgView32.Bitmap, FFile[i].Points, FFile[i].Color, true, 3);


      LinearGradFiller.Free;

      with TText32.Create do
      begin
            Draw(ImgView32.Bitmap, trunc(FFile[i].Rect.Left)+10, trunc(FFile[i].Rect.Top)+12, FFile[i].Caption, ttfcArial16, clWhite32);
      end;
      //SimpleText(ImgView32.Bitmap, Font, trunc(FFile[i].Rect.Left)+10, trunc(FFile[i].Rect.Top)+10, FFile[i].Caption,clWhite32);
    end;
  end;
end;
```

That works as well, and certainly more beautiful than the Paintbox-descendant. But, when I place more then 10 objects on the form, moving the objects is a drama; very slow and hesitant. Adding text made things worse.

Currently I am testing with creating descendants of TPaintbox32, but, well, I don't know. I'm not sure about this. Before continueing my test, how would you solve this :

- different anti-aliased painted objects
- 2 color gradient filled
- the object must contain text
- an object should be able to move by using the mouse. The moving must be smooth
- certain objects have lines (arrows) between them. Preferably I want the lines to be draw during movement of objects
- the drawing and moving must be fluid indepent of the number of objects. It needs to be smooth even if there are 30-50 objects

Please check the code below. It is a form I am testing with, and already stripped comments. Clicking the button will create a new rounded rectangle. Click and hold to move such a rectangle. That goes smooth with less than 10 rectangles, but with more it works like shit. 
I'm new to graphics programming, new to the graphics32 library. Please help me out.

```
unit bollen32;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, GR32, GR32_Image, GR32_Layers, GR32_ColorGradients,
  GR32_Paths, GR32_Polygons, GR32_ArrowHeads, Vcl.ComCtrls, GR32_Text,
  Vcl.StdCtrls, Vcl.ExtCtrls, System.UITypes;

type
  TFile = record
    Color:         TColor32;
    Rect:          TFloatRect;
    Points:        TArrayOfFloatPoint;
    Width:         integer;
    Height:        integer;
    GradientFrom:  TFloatPoint;
    GradientTo:    TFloatPoint;
    Caption:       string;
  end;

  TForm3 = class(TForm)
    ImgView32: TImgView32;
    StatusBar1: TStatusBar;
    Panel1: TPanel;
    Button1: TButton;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure ImgView32MouseDown(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton; Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer; Layer: TCustomLayer);
    procedure ImgView32MouseMove(Sender: TObject; Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer; Layer: TCustomLayer);
    procedure ImgView32MouseUp(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton;  Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer; Layer: TCustomLayer);
    procedure FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
    FFile:         Array of TFile;
    FFileCount:    integer;
    FFileSelect:   integer;

    FGradient:         TColor32Gradient;
    FGradientLUT:      TColor32LookupTable;
    LinearGradFiller:  TLinearGradientPolygonFiller;

    FLastPos:      TPoint;
    FText32:       TText32;
    ttfcArial16:   TTrueTypeFont;

    procedure ReDraw;
  public
    { Public declarations }
    procedure AddFile;

    property FileSelect: integer   read FFileSelect write FFileSelect;
  end;

const
  COLOR1 = $FF2B178F;
  COLOR2 = $FF5367C1;

var
  Form3: TForm3;

implementation
uses clipbrd, GR32_LowLevel, GR32_Geometry, GR32_VectorUtils;

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm3.AddFile;
var
  i:  integer;
begin
  i := Length(FFile);
  FFileCount := FFileCount + 1;

  if FFileCount > i-1 then
    SetLength(FFile, FFileCount+1);

  FFile[FFileCount].Width  := Random(150)+50;
  FFile[FFileCount].Height := Random(150)+50;

  FFile[FFileCount].Rect.Left := Random(ImgView32.Width)+30;
  FFile[FFileCount].Rect.Top  := Random(Height)+30;
  FFile[FFileCount].Rect.Right := FFile[FFileCount].Rect.Left + FFile[FFileCount].Width;
  FFile[FFileCount].Rect.Bottom := FFile[FFileCount].Rect.Top + FFile[FFileCount].Height;

  FFile[FFileCount].Points    := RoundRect(FFile[i].Rect, 20);

  FFile[FFileCOunt].GradientFrom.X := FFile[FFileCount].Rect.Left;
  FFile[FFileCOunt].GradientFrom.Y := (FFile[FFileCount].Rect.Bottom-FFile[FFileCount].Rect.Top)/2;
  FFile[FFileCOunt].GradientTo.X   := FFile[FFileCount].Rect.Right;
  FFile[FFileCOunt].GradientTo.Y   := FFile[FFileCOunt].GradientFrom.Y;

  FFile[FFileCount].Caption := 'Hello '+IntToStr(FFileCount+1);

  ReDraw;
end;

procedure TForm3.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  AddFile;
end;

procedure TForm3.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Left := 50;
  Top  := 50;
  Width := Screen.Width - 100;
  Height := Screen.Height - 100;

  ImgView32.Bitmap.DrawMode := dmOpaque;
  ImgView32.SetupBitmap(True, clWhite32);

  FGradient := TColor32Gradient.Create;
  FGradient.AddColorStop(0.2, COLOR1);
  FGradient.AddColorStop(0.8, COLOR2);

  FGradientLUT := TColor32LookupTable.Create;

  LinearGradFiller          := TLinearGradientPolygonFiller.Create(FGradientLUT);
  LinearGradFiller.WrapMode := TWrapMode(0);

  FGradient.FillColorLookUpTable(FGradientLUT);

  SetLength(FFile, 0);

  FFileCount := -1;
  FileSelect := -1;

  FText32 := TText32.Create;
  ttfcArial16 := TrueTypeFontClass.Create('Arial', 16, [fsBold]);
end;

procedure TForm3.FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
begin
  LinearGradFiller.Free;
  FText32.Free;
end;

procedure TForm3.ImgView32MouseDown(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton;
  Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer; Layer: TCustomLayer);
var
  b:  boolean;
  i:  integer;
begin
  Caption := 'Clicked';

  for i := Length(FFile)-1 downto 0 do
  begin
    b := PointInPolygon(FloatPoint(x,y), FFile[i].Points);

    if b then
    begin
      FLastPos   := Point(X, Y);
      FileSelect := i;
      Caption    := 'Selected!';
      Exit;
    end;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm3.ImgView32MouseMove(Sender: TObject; Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer; Layer: TCustomLayer);
begin
  if FileSelect > -1 then
  begin
    FFile[FileSelect].Rect.Left := FLastPos.X;
    FFile[FileSelect].Rect.Top  := FLastPos.Y;
    FFile[FileSelect].Rect      := FloatRect(FLastPos.X, FLastPos.Y, FLastPos.X+FFile[FileSelect].Width, FLastPos.Y+FFile[FileSelect].Height);
    FFile[FileSelect].Points    := RoundRect(FFile[FFileSelect].Rect, 20);

    FFile[FFileSelect].GradientFrom.X := FFile[FFileSelect].Rect.Left;
    FFile[FFileSelect].GradientFrom.Y := (FFile[FFileSelect].Rect.Bottom-FFile[FFileSelect].Rect.Top)/2;
    FFile[FFileSelect].GradientTo.X   := FFile[FFileSelect].Rect.Right;
    FFile[FFileSelect].GradientTo.Y   := FFile[FFileSelect].GradientFrom.Y;

    FLastPos := Point(X, Y);

    Redraw;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm3.ImgView32MouseUp(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton;
  Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer; Layer: TCustomLayer);
begin
  FileSelect := -1;
end;

procedure TForm3.ReDraw;
var
  i:  integer;
begin
  ImgView32.Bitmap.Clear(clWhite32);

  if FFileCount > -1 then
  begin
    ImgView32.BeginUpdate;
    for i := 0 to Length(FFile)-1 do
    begin
      LinearGradFiller.StartPoint := FFile[i].GradientFrom;
      LinearGradFiller.EndPoint   := FFile[i].GradientTo;

      PolygonFS(ImgView32.Bitmap, FFile[i].Points, LinearGradFiller);
      PolyLineFS(ImgView32.Bitmap, FFile[i].Points, clRed32, true, 3);

      FText32.Draw(ImgView32.Bitmap, trunc(FFile[i].Rect.Left)+10, trunc(FFile[i].Rect.Top)+20, FFile[i].Caption, ttfcArial16, clWhite32);
    end;
    ImgView32.EndUpdate;
  end;
end;

end.
```

Comment: I have had no trouble getting good performing animated drawing with graphics32

Comment: On a side-note, it's not really necessary to descend from a `TPaintBox`. That's typically meant for people who want to make graphics but *don't* want to deal with components. Instead, just create a raw custom control, for example descending from `TCustomControl`. That *might* help just a tad with performance.

Comment: Of course it matters what gets redrawn. Be sure to only redraw objects that need to be redrawn, i.e. the moved obejcts and the objects covered by them and their connecting lines. That way you should be able to handle larger numbers of objects. The objects that are not affected don't matter, so there can be hundreds of them.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis 
but how do I know which objects needs repainting ?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan
Could you tell me in general how you did that ? I mean, did you just use an TImgView32, or the TPaintBox32, or did you use layers ?

Comment: I'm still in need for some starters advice, maybe especially on the text-part since that seems a bottleneck.

Comment: @Arthur: those that move and those that are crossed by them or the connecting line. You'll have to check that in code.

Comment: I draw onto a TBitmap 32 and then blit that to the screen